# The backgroundHandler needs to be either a static function or a top level function

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

If I tap a notification that I have already received after exiting the app, I want the second app to start after the app is launched.

Defining the backgroundHandler outside of the class, before the runapp (toplevel) did not resolve the error.

The code is shared below.

```
    class PushNotification {
        void setNotification(id, type, title, body) async {
        final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin 
            flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
                FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

        DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
        const DarwinInitializationSettings(
          requestSoundPermission: true,
          requestBadgePermission: true,
          requestAlertPermission: true,
        );

        const DarwinNotificationDetails iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
            DarwinNotificationDetails(
                presentAlert: true, presentBadge: true, presentSound: true);

        late InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
          iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
          android: const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher'),
    );

        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,

        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (details) async {
        await notificationOpenHandler(Id, type);
      },

      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: (details) {
        notificationBackOpenHandler(Id, type);
      },
    );
}
```

Handlers for background notification taps are listed outside the class in the same file.

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
    Future<void> notificationBackOpenHandler(Id, type) async {
  NotificationAppLaunchDetails? launchDetail =
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
  debugPrint('_notificationBackOpenHandler launchDetail: $launchDetail');

  if (launchDetail != null) {

    if (launchDetail.didNotificationLaunchApp) {

      if (launchDetail.notificationResponse?.payload == null) {

        final Uri flutterUrl = Uri.parse(
            'https://liff.line.me/{liffid}/{urlname}?id=$Id');

        await launchUrl(
          flutterUrl,
          mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
        );
      } else if (launchDetail.notificationResponse?.payload != null) {
        Id = launchDetail.notificationResponse?.payload;
        final Uri flutterUrl = Uri.parse(
            'https://liff.line.me/{liffid}/{urlname}?id=$Id');

        await launchUrl(
          flutterUrl,
          mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
        );
      }
    } else {

      final Uri flutterUrl = Uri.parse(
          'https://liff.line.me/{liffid}/{urlname}?id=$Id');

      await launchUrl(
        flutterUrl,
        mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
      );
    }
  } else {

  }
}
```

Comment: Kindly share your code.

Comment: @HarshSureja
Share code.
The following error occurs when initializing the filterLocalNotificationsPlugin.

`The backgroundHandler needs to be either a static function or a top level function to be accessible as a Flutter entry point.`

Comment: is able to solve putting `static` before `Future<void>` ?

Comment: @HarshSureja
I moved the handler in the class and added `static`, but the same error occurs.

Comment: I was able to solve it with reference to this answer.
[link](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/issues/1877#issuecomment-1439522272)